# Search column and return something based on a few criteria

Tags: excel, vba

How would I write VBA for the below table that will return the word REVIEW in the Note column, if I have difference Prices for the same Payee in a given month?

For example, in January 2020, the Payee "ABC" has Prices of 2 and 3 (these are different, they should be the same), so I want to return REVIEW in the Note column

Example:

| Date | Customer | Price | Note | Payee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | Johnson | 2 | REVIEW | ABC |
| 1/1/2020 | McGuire | 3 | REVIEW | ABC |
| 1/1/2020 | Miller | 2 |  | XYZ |

Answer (score 1):

This can very likely be done with Excel standard functionality like COUNTIFS etc. If you look for a VBA solution and would like to learn some basic stuff one could use the dictionary in the following way.

```
Option Explicit
Function addReview()
    Const DELIMITER = ","
    Const REVIEW = "REVIEW"
    
    ' adjust accordingly
    ' This code just assumes data is in the active sheet on the top left
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion               ' range with headers
    Set rg = rg.Offset(1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1)  ' range without the headers
        
    Dim vDat As Variant
    vDat = rg.Value             ' write data into an array in memory
    
    Dim key
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dVal As dictMember
    
    ' In case of Early binding Add Tools/Reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
    'Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = LBound(vDat, 1) To UBound(vDat, 1)
        
        ' Key is month of the date column and Payee
        key = Month(vDat(i, 1)) & vDat(i, 5)
        
        If dict.Exists(key) Then
            ' add the row in anycase
            dict.Item(key).lines = dict.Item(key).lines & DELIMITER & CStr(i)
            
            ' if entry exist check if price is not equal
            If dict.Item(key).price <> vDat(i, 3) Then
                ' price not equal => review is true
                dict.Item(key).REVIEW = True
            End If
            
        Else
            ' no entry in the dictionary yet
            ' create new dictMember
            Set dVal = New dictMember
            dVal.lines = CStr(i)     ' add row nr
            dVal.price = vDat(i, 3)  ' add the price
            dVal.REVIEW = False      ' check if review false
            dict.Add key, dVal       ' add to the dictionary
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Loop through the dictionary
    Dim sngLine
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        ' check if "REVIEW" should be added
        If dict.Item(key).REVIEW Then
            ' add "REVIEW"
            For Each sngLine In Split(dict.Item(key).lines, DELIMITER)
                vDat(CLng(sngLine), 4) = REVIEW
            Next
        End If
        
    Next key
    
    ' write modfied data back to sheet
    ' on could restrict it to the column in question- Up to the OP
    rg.Value = vDat
    
End Function
```

Reading on [Dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) resp. [Storing Multiple Values in One Key](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Storing_Multiple_Values_in_One_Key)

Reading on [Range](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-range-cells/#Reading_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array/) and [Reading a Range of Cells to an Array](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-range-cells/#Reading_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array/)

**PS** I forgot to add the class (Insert/Class Module) `dictMember`. Please find below

```
Option Explicit
' "Class" to hold the dictionary member
Public price As Double
Public lines As String
Public REVIEW As Boolean
```

Comment: Thanks you, I'll give this a try later and will read your provided sources!